# Unable to set variable in AWS pgsql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a dynamic location for create external table statement.

I am using the statement

```
@set loc = 's3/root/' + Replace(Convert (Varchar, Current_Date),'-','')
```

In order to  set loc to `'s3/root/20200622'` but I am unable to do it, while the select gives expected result.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid PostgreSQL syntax at all. There are no variables in PostgresSQL.

Comment: I am using dbvweaver for Amazon redshift

Comment: I'll remove the PostgreSQL tag, since this is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't support variables.

You can either create a Python UDF to to this, but I'm not sure even that'll serve your use-case.

You can execute the queries using Python code and pass the filenames dynamically from Python.